# In Romans 1:24 is Paul's usage of ακαθαρσιαν [G167 N-ASF] the same as in Leviticus 5:3?

Tags: word-study, romans

In Romans 1:24 is Paul's usage of ακαθαρσιαν [G167 N-ASF] the same as in Leviticus 5:3?

> Brenton Lev 5:2  That soul which shall touch any unclean (ακαθαρτου
>   G169 A-GSN) thing, or carcase, or that which is unclean being taken of
>   beasts, or the dead bodies of abominable reptiles which are unclean,
>   or carcases of unclean cattle,  Lev 5:3  or should touch the
>   uncleanness (ακαθαρσιας G167 N-GSF) of a man, or whatever kind, which
>   he may touch and be defiled by, and it should have escaped him, but
>   afterwards he should know, --then he shall have transgressed.

It seems very obvious that Jesus is referring to the "uncleanness" of which the Torah spoke:

> ISV Mat 23:27  "How terrible it will be for you, scribes and
>   Pharisees, you hypocrites! You are like whitewashed tombs that look
>   beautiful on the outside but inside are full of dead people's bones
>   and every kind of impurity (ακαθαρσιας G167 N-GSF).

But what about Paul? When he speaks of "uncleanness" (usually rendered "impurity") is he using the word in the same sense as in the LXX? Or is it a more secular usage?:

> English Standard Version Therefore God gave them up in the lusts of
>   their hearts to impurity (ακαθαρσιαν G167 N-ASF), to the dishonoring
>   of their bodies among themselves,

Comment: For those to whom it was not obvious (it wasn't to me): it appears that the OP is including after the word of interest a Strong's number followed by an encoded parsing (**N**oun: **G**enitive | **A**ccusative **S**ingular **F**eminine)

Comment: @Susan  Thanks. I included the parsing because... well... I forget!

Answer (score 2):

ἀκαθαρσία occurs over 60 times in the Septuagint and is used in many places to refer to something other than ritual impurity.  For example:

> *For he rejoices in all things which God hates, and is ruined by reason of **impurity** of soul* (Proverbs 6:16 LXX)
>
> *We are esteemed of him as counterfeits: he abstaineth from our ways as from **filthiness**: he pronounceth the end of the just to be blessed, and maketh his boast that God is his father* (Wisdom 2:16)

What Paul might be alluding to in Romans 1:24 is the Wisdom of Solomon and not Leviticus:

> *For the devising of idols was the beginning of spiritual fornication, and the invention of them the corruption of life* (Wisdom 14:12)

The "uncleanness" that Paul has in mind seems to be sexual impurity and not ritual uncleanness.  He uses the same word (ἀκαθαρσία) in 2 Corinthians (12:21):

> *And lest, when I come again, my God will humble me among you, and that I shall bewail many which have sinned already, and have not repented of the uncleanness and fornication and lasciviousness which they have committed.*

Comment: Yes, Paul sees impurity as not only affecting the body but also a problem of "the heart":  NIV 2 Cor 7:1   
Therefore, since we have these promises, dear friends, let us purify ourselves **from everything that contaminates body and spirit**, perfecting holiness out of reverence for God.